# How to represent a Board Panel in Java for a game?

Tags: java, user-interface

I wanna fix a 2D board for a game. I've already fixed other panels for the Gui and everything goes well. But the panel for the board cant be printed on the window. I'm a bit confused about it as i think i've followed the same ideas as for the others panels i need.

Here's what i've done:

**EDIT**:
what I'm trying to do is fix a board panel for the game according to the dimensions of the it,hold every square in an array in order to use it after wherever it;s needed. I draw each little square of it with the method draw and put it back to the panel. So, each square on the board is a panel. This is the idea. But as u can see. There are troubles/errors on it.

EDIT: code updated.
just found a part of the problem. i thought first that i had set background to squared, but i didnt. with this one it appears on the panel a wide black "column". Unfortunately,still none squares. :(

One More EDIT:
Also,i realized that draw method is never called. when i put the draw method in the following method i can see the squares but they remain small. I redefine them with setSize but still no change.

**How can I use paint method to edit the panels properly???? As it is now it can't. Even it can't return an object(eg panel) as it's polymorphic void!**

```
/**
    *Method used to construct the square in the area of the
    *gui's grid. In this stage a GUISquare array is being constructed, 
    * used in the whole game as
    *a mean of changing a square graphical state.
    *@param squares is the squares array from whom the gui grid will be
    *constructed.
    *@see getSquare about the correspondance beetween a squareModel and
    * a GUISquare.
    */
    private void initBoardPanel(SquareModel[][] squares){

         BoardPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(height ,width )); //set layout

         SquareRenderer[][] Squares;
         JPanel[][] grid;
         Squares=new GUISquare[height][width()];
         grid=new JPanel[height()][width()];

         for (int i=0; i<height(); i++){
                for (int j=0; j<width() ; j++){
                    SquareRenderer kou=new SquareRenderer(i,j);
                kou.setSquare(myGame.getSquares()[i][j]);
                      //NOTE: THE FOLLOWING DRAW METHOD CANT BE CALLED!!!?
                if (myGame.getSquares()[i][j] instanceof SimpleSq  ){
                        kou .paintPanel(i,j,"");}
                else if (myGame.getSquares()[i][j] instanceof ActionSq  )
                {       kou .paintPanel(i,j);
                }
                   //JUST BECAUSE DRAW CANT BE CALLED I PUT ITS CODE HERE: 
                   //JUST TO CHECK:
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Move To "+myGame.getSquares()[i][j].getGoTo());
                JLabel label2 = new JLabel(""+myGame.getSquares()[i][j].getSquare());

                panel.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
                panel.add(label2, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                panel.add(label1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                panel.setSize(250,250);

                    /////////  <--until here ---paint method<---

                kou.add(panel);
                kou.setVisible(true);
                kou.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

                Squares[i][j]= kou;

                BoardPanel.add(kou);
                BoardPanel.setVisible(true);
                BoardPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE); 
                }
        }
        this.add(BoardPanel,BorderLayout.WEST);
     //   this.pack(); //sets appropriate size for frame
        this.setVisible(true); //makes frame visible
}
```

IMPLEMENTED BY SQUARERENDERER:

```
/**
 * Transformer for Snake/Ladder
 * <br>This method is used to display a square on the screen.
 */
public void paintPanel(int i,int j) {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Move To"+myGame.getSquares()[i][j].getGoTo());
    JLabel label2 = new JLabel(""+myGame.getSquares()[i][j].getSquare());
    JSeparator CellSeparator = new JSeparator(orientation);
    panel.add(CellSeparator);
    panel.setForeground(Color.ORANGE);
    panel.add(label2, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    panel.add(label1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

Comment: Suggestion: instead of checking the type of the square, have each class implement a `drawSquare` method that takes in a `GUISquare`. It makes your board initialize method cleaner and better encapsulates your code.

Comment: That would be better you are right. I just left the "cleaning" of code for after. Now i just wanna end with the section of graphics :/ thnx for the tip anw

Comment: I'm not sure what your current problem is based on your question and your code. You may wish to provide us with more detail.  Also unholysampler's suggestion is not just about "cleaning" your code. If your code is simpler as he suggests, it will be easier for you and us to debug.

Comment: should i provide the whole code? it's quite difficult. you can ask me whatever. in any case i will try to post more details...

Comment: just found a part of the problem. again updated.

Comment: once more. update. im close to solution. just keep posting for others who maybe have similar probs.

Answer (score 2):

I see a couple things that are problematic:

1. When using a layout manager, you should avoid calling setSize.  Most layout managers will simply override it.  You should use setPreferredSize, setMinimumSize, and setMaximumSize instead, which provide hints to the layout manager.
2. It doesn't look like the draw method of SquareRenderer ever adds the panel you create to anything.  You should either add panel to the SquareRenderer in the last line of draw or (better) add the sub-components directly to the SquareRenderer instead.

Comment: Thanks for the first. i didn't know that. As for the second one,i noticed that->see update. Problem is that draw method is never been called. searching why.

Comment: You shouldn't need to override any of the awt or swing paint components for what you're trying to do here(for a primer on painting in swing see http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/).  You just need to make sure that you initialize the components correctly(i.e. make sure everything is added to the component hierarchy) and set the size hints correctly.  It looks like you're still using setSize in the example above, try using the methods I mentioned above to specify the component size

Comment: could you give an example pls? i dont wanna use graphics().